# pyqtgraph exporting SVG messy/shifting

Tags: python, qt, svg, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have this code to generate a figure:

**The code:**

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph.exporters


pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(
    0, 10, size=(1000, 11)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJK'))

win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
# win.resize(900, 600)
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')

# Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

ndays = 5
ngenos = df.shape[1]
nrows = 3
ncols = 4
p = ['p%s' % s for s in range(ngenos)]
bg = ['bg%s' % s for s in range(ngenos * ndays)]
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setPixelSize(5)

for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        if (i * ncols + j) < ngenos:
            p[i * ncols + j] = win.addPlot(title=df.dtypes.index[i * ncols + j])
            for k in range(ndays):
                bg[(i * ncols + j) + k] = pg.BarGraphItem(x=range(200), y0=(10 * k), height=df.iloc[: 200*(k+1), (i * ncols + j)], width=0.3)
                p[i * ncols + j].addItem(bg[(i * ncols + j) + k])
            # p[i * ncols + j].showGrid(x=None, y=True)
            p[i * ncols + j].setRange(xRange=(0, 200), yRange=(0, 60))
            p[i * ncols + j].getAxis('bottom').tickFont = font
            p[i * ncols + j].getAxis('left').tickFont = font

    win.nextRow()


QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
ex = pg.exporters.SVGExporter(win.scene())
ex.export('test2.svg')
ex = pg.exporters.ImageExporter(win.scene())
ex.export('test2.png')

pg.cleanup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

The png file looks fine but the resolution is very low. In the SVG file, it seems that all the axis have shifted.

**The png file:**
[image]

**The SVG file:**
[image]

How could I make the SVG export right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and get the same output as you.

This is a bug in PyQtGraph that already has been reported: [see issue #434](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/434).

There seem to be some other long standing open issues in the SVG export (issues [105](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/105) and [176](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/176)), so I wouldn't count on a quick fix.

Perhaps you can try and have a go at it yourself. There is some postprocessing done in [SVGExporter.py](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/exporters/SVGExporter.py) to work around some issues with Qt's SVG generator, and my gut feeling is that the bug is in there.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully they would fix it soon.